# An efficient algorithm to sort millions of words in a DoubleLinkedList

Tags: java, performance, sorting, linked-list, search-engine

I'm working on a simple search engine in Java.

The search engine takes first as input the name of the directory that contains the files(txt files) to be searched , and inside each file many words.

The search engine then creates an inverted index for all the words encountered in the 
directory. The engine reads each file and insert each word in the doubleLinkedList.

The problem is, when I deal with a directory that contains 100 .txt files:

Indexing Time: ~201ms
sort Time: 2463ms

---

sorting a directory contains 1000 files

Indexing Time: 2461ms
sort Time: 922654ms

---

sorting a directory contains 10000 files

**around 10 hours :(**

---

1. Is there any possible way to reduce the execution time?
2. I used the insertion sort, so any suggestions for the sort algorithm?

The implementation of the DoubleLinkedList class

```
public class DoubleLinkedList<T> {
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> current;

    public DoubleLinkedList(){
        head = current = null;
    }
    public boolean empty(){
        return head == null;
    }
    public boolean last(){
        return current.next==null;
    }
    public boolean first(){
        return current.previous == null;
    }
    public boolean full(){
        return false;
    }
    public void findFirst(){
        current = head;
    }
    public void findNext(){
        current = current.next;
    }
    public void findPrevious(){
        current = current.previous;
    }
    public T retrieve(){
        return current.data;
    }
    public void update(T val){
        current.data = val;
    }
    public void insert(T val){
        if(head == null){
            head = current = new Node<T>(val);
        }else{
            Node<T> tmp = new Node<T>(val);
            tmp.next = current.next;
            tmp.previous = current;
            if(current.next != null)
                current.next.previous = tmp;
            current.next = tmp;
            current = tmp;
        }
    }
    public void remove(){
        if(current == head){
            head = head.next;
            if(head!=null){
                head.previous=null;
            }
        }else{
            current.previous.next = current.next;
            if(current.next!=null){
                current.next.previous = current.previous;
            }
        }
        if(current.next == null){
            current = head;
        }else{
            current = current.next;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Change your sort algorithm for a `O(n log n)` one like [QuickSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) or for a `O(n)` like [RadixSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Comment: Can I suggest that for a search engine, relying on any kind of sortedness is not going to scale very well?

Comment: @Mohammad:What do you mean you used insertSort?Didn't you do: `Collections.sort(doubleLinkedList)`?This is mergesort

Comment: @Cratylus No, i used a different DoubleLinkedList. I didn't use anything form "Collections".

Comment: @Mohammad:It is not a standard collection?You came up with your own datastructure? So essentially you came up with your own implementation of double-link list, your own implementation of insert sort and 1)You complaint that you have performance issue 2)you don't post your code?

Comment: @Cratylus sorry, I forgot:). I took the implementation from a Data Structure course in the university. I will post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insertion sort runs in (worst case) `O(n^2)` time.

You could try something like Mergesort, QuickSort, or HeapSort, which run in (IIRC) `O(nlogn)` time.  This will be much faster.

Comment: At least add that a DoubleLinkedList it's not a good data structure for sorting operations instead of providing some answers based from my comment =\.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I wrote my answer before seeing your comment.  I am sorry if you received the impression that I was copying your comment down into an answer--I did not do so.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is a faster way. In fact, there are [dozens of faster ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) :-)

But unless you like reinventing the wheel, you could simply use `Collections.sort(list)`. Also, if performance matters, I recommend using an `ArrayList` rather a `LinkedList`, as it permits better locality of reference and takes up less memory.

For a list of length 10000, this ought to reduce execution time by 3 orders of magnitude (i.e. by a factor of 1000) compared to an insertion sort.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ArrayList`, then call `list.trim()` to remove empty reserved list space, then simply call `Collections.sort(list)`. The `LinkedList` is in 99,5 % worse than `ArrayList`.

If that still is to slow: next simply try: 
using  `ArrayList`, build a `String[] words`, and sort with `Arrays.sort( words)`
.
Collection.sort uses a (modified) MergeSort.

> This algorithm offers guaranteed n log(n) performance.

You can do a bit faster by avoiding the overhead of the collections, I have done that once using MyArrayListInt with Quicksort.